# How to create a blob / clob?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

At the moment I have hibernate JPA HSQLDB to auto-create my database tables.

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />`

How can I tell JPA or Hibernate to save a String as a clob/blob field? Ie a very long String. I could not find any annotation so far. How must I configure this on eg a
`private String myBigContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help :)

```
  @Column( name = "FILEIMAGE" )
    @Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
    private byte[] fileimage;
```

Comment: Just for reference. As written I use HSQLDB, which has a serious Bug which is still not fixed in the 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT release. Using @Lob, it always results in a `unsupported internal operation: Session` Exception. Therefore I switched to `@Column(length = 2147483647)` which should do the same as lob.